# Neos CMS 7: How do you organize menus in the CR

Tags: neoscms

How are the menus organized in the Content Repository (CR)? Namely, a main menu, a meta menu, and a footer menu. Is there any obvious disadvantage to using this CR:

```
Home
|- Main Menu (ID 1)
   |- Blog
   |- Products
   |- Services
   |- ..
|- Meta Menu (ID 2)
   |- Contact Us
   |- ..
|- Footer Menu (ID 3)
   |- Privacy Terms 
   |- Imprint
   |- ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We normally assume that the "normal" pages showing up in the "main menu" are directly underneath the Site Node (in your example "Home").

For additional menus like meta or footer, we create a Document Node of type Folder. The package [neos/nodetypes-folder](https://www.neos.io/de/download/pakete/breadlesscode/breadlesscode-neos-nodetypes-folder.html) provides such a Node Type. It also allows you to exclude the path segment generated by the folder (e.g. `meta-menu`) from the URL so you have nice URLs in the frontend but still a clean backend.